# Array of pointers to pointers: managing strings for different languages

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I currently have a lot of character arrays that store simple character strings in English for display. I also have pointers to these character arrays.

```
char helloAr[20] = "Hello";
char timeAr[20] = "Time";
char dogAr[20] = "Dog";

char* helloPtr = helloAr;
char* timePtr = timeAr;
char* dogPtr = dogAr;
```

I am adding more character arrays in a different language, French to begin with.

```
char helloArFr[20] = "Bonjour";
char timeArFr[20] = "temps";
char dogArFr[20] = "chien";
```

If the user selects French I plan to change the address that all my pointers (currently pointing at the English character arrays) point to, so they now point to the French character arrays. I assume I can simply assign a new values to these pointers to do this,

```
helloPtr = helloArFr;
timePtr = timeArFr;
dogPtr = dogArFr;
```

however my actual code will have a lot of arrays so I wanted to use a loop to do this rather than lots of statements like the one above.

To do this I plan to create an array of character pointers to the addresses of my character arrays.

```
char* charArrAddresses [NUMBER_OF_TEXT_ARRAYS]=
{
    &helloAr,
    &timeAr,
    &dogAr,
    &helloArFr,
    &timeArFr,
    &dogArFr,
};
```

I also plan to store all the pointers in an array so that I can reference them by their location in the array in my single statement, but this is where I need some help as I am unsure on how to do this. Something like this maybe?

```
char ** langPtrs[NUMBER_OF_LANG_POINTERS]=
{
    helloPtr,
    timePtr,
    dogPtr,
};
```

In the single statement inside the loop I will use the selected language and the number of char arrays to calculate the correct index for `charArrAddresses`, lets call this `X` for now. I will use the value of my loop (say `i`) to index my `langPtrs` array.  So in my single want to say something like,

```
for(i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_LANG_POINTERS; i++)
{
    langPtrs[i]= charArrAddresses[X];
}
```

I am trying to assign the address of the character array stored in index `X` of `charArrAddresses` to the pointer in index `i` in the `langPtrs` array. I just need help on exactly how to declare the `langPtrs` array and on how to write my single statement above.

Comment: first choose a language, second use `std::string` if you chose c++

Comment: I'm assuming @user463035818 meant that you should choose a programming language. c and c++ are very different languages, despite the apparent similarities. I don't think he meant you should choose a single speaking language. Since the question is about multilingual support, I thought it might be important to make that distinction.

Comment: ... uff yes of course, missed that possible misunderstanding. I appreciate your efforts to support multiple languages, but when it comes to code you better pick one programming lanuage

Comment: It may be simpler to use a std::vector<std::string>> then when you will need to access the data the only thing changing is the vector. (each vector corresponding to a language)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am working on code that was written by someone else so I am tied down to using the char strings & char string pointers, the char strings and their pointers, as well as some other arrays of pointers to those pointers are tied into the code in so many places (classes, methods, display/printing functions etc) that I cannot change how this works. I am simply trying to use what is there and implement the example above. Has anyone any idea on how I attack my issues with the idea above?, how to declare the langPtrs array correctly and how to write my single statement above?

Answer (score 9):

Rather than placing the strings for all languages in a single array, make a 2D array of strings and languages.  If you don't plan on modifying any of these strings, you can make them string literals instead of arrays.

```
enum langs {
    LANG_ENGLISH,
    LANG_FRENCH,
    NUMBER_OF_LANGS
};

enum strings{
    STR_HELLO,
    STR_TIME,
    STR_DOG,
    NUMBER_OF_STRINGS
};

const char *langPtrs[NUMBER_OF_LANGS][NUMBER_OF_STRINGS]=
{
    { "Hello", "Time", "Dog" }
    { "Bonjour", "temps", "chien" }
};
```

Since the values of the symbols in an `enum` start at 0 and increment by 1 for each subsequent symbol, you can use them an array indexes.  The last member of each `enum`, which does not correspond to an actual element in the array, can be used as the size of the array.

So if you want to, for example, print the string for "time" in French, you would use:

```
printf("%s\n", langPtrs[LANG_FRENCH][STR_TIME]);
```

If you want to always print string from whatever the "current" language is, you can create a pointer to the subarray for the current language:

```
const char **currentLang = langPtrs[LANG_FRENCH];
```

Then you can use that:

```
printf("%s\n", currentLang[STR_TIME]);
```

EDIT:

If you want to keep `helloPtr`, `timePtr`, and `dogPtr`, and you want to set them based on the current language, you can put their addresses in another array:

```
const char **usedInClassesPtrs[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS] = {
    &helloPtr,
    &timePtr,
    &dogPtr
}
```

Then loop through the array, dereferencing each element to give you the actual pointers you want to change, and assign them a string from the 2D language array based on the current language as follows:

```
for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++) {
    *usedInClassesPtrs[i] = langPtrs[currentLang][i];
}
```

Comment: If C++, and you really want the pointers to refer to string literals directly, then you're going to have to put `const` in there. Probably not a terrible idea in C, either?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: Nice. However I tend to start such kind of enums like this: `enum langs {INVALID_LANGUAGE = -1, 
    LANG_ENGLISH, ...`

Comment: Hi dbush , Thanks for the comment, I am actually already using enums for the indexs as you suggested in a lot of other places in my code, love the idea of the 2D array, it was actually something I was going to look into as the start and it completely slipped my mind, also thank you for the sample code I will 100% try to use implement it . My main issue is that I am working on code that was written by someone else so I am tied down to using the char strings and char string pointers, the char strings and their pointers, as well as some other arrays of pointers to those pointers (1 of 2)

Comment: are tied into the code in so many places (classes, methods, display/printing functions etc) that it would be a nightmare to change how this works (although I will definitely try after reading your answer). In case I cannot manage to change the code due to the large amount of dependencies on how the strings are currently stored would you have any idea on how I attack my issues with my idea above?, how to declare the langPtrs array correctly and how to write my single statement above? (2 of 2)

Comment: @user1649972 You can keep the format of 2D array, but instead of string constants you would put the names of each specific string, i.e. `const char *langPtrs[NUMBER_OF_LANGS][NUMBER_OF_STRINGS]= { { helloAr, timeAr, dogAr }, { helloArFr, timeArFr, dogArFr } };`

Comment: @dbush, thanks again. The printing is already handled elsewhere in various screen/menu/display classes so I don’t want to change that. Those classes use the pointers to the char arrays (char* helloPtr etc.) to print so my plan is to simply point the char pointers to the character arrays of the newly selected language.  That way all the classes, methods etc. operate in the same way using the contents of the character pointers, but the character pointers now simply point at different arrays (the character arrays of the newly language selected). (1 of 3)

Comment: If I create a 2D array as you suggested  i.e. 
`const char *langPtrs[NUMBER_OF_LANGS][NUMBER_OF_STRINGS]= { { helloAr, timeAr, dogAr }, { helloArFr, timeArFr, dogArFr } }; `
I will still have the old char pointers and still need to point these char pointers (char* helloPtr etc.) to the arrays stored in my new 2D array based on the language selected. To do this I will need all my original char pointers in an array so that I can reference them in a for loop using an index. (2 of 3)

Comment: So again I need help to understand how to correctly write this so that my for loop assigns the address of the char array in my 2D array to the char pointer in my array of character pointers to character pointers. Would below work?
`char ** usedInClassesPtrs[NUMBER_OF_CHAR_POINTERS]=
{
    helloPtr,
    timePtr,
    dogPtr,
};`
And then write
`for(i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_CHAR_POINTERS; i++)
{
    usedInClassesPtrs [i]= charArrAddresses [selectedLang][i];
}`
(3 of 3)

Comment: @user1649972 See my edit.  It should address what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

The @debush answer should work quite well. 
From your example i assume that only 1 language is active at a time in your code. For that, i suggest to use a resource approach to manage your multi-language support. You can basically load the corresponding resource file of a language and store it in `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::map<const enum/id/etc., std::string>` or any similar data structure. This can be done either on the fly or at initialization stage depending on your need. In your code you save a pointer to this data structure `std::vector<std::string>* ptr` to refer to currently loaded language by invoking `(*ptr)[index]`.